# Sharing TCP socket between application in linux

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcpsocket, tcpsocket, qtcpserver

I want to share the existing TCP socket from the main application to the second one on the device and continue communication with the client. Applications work in the Linux system. I found in QAbstractSocket [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#BindFlag-enum) that I should bind the socket with mode **QAbstractSocket::ShareAddress**, but I can't achieve a working example. I tried to share the socket using a socket descriptor or create a **QTcpSocket** object with the IP address and port.

The demo implementation server-side

**[First application]**

Reimplemented *incomingConnection* on the server:

```
void InternalTcpServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
    QTcpSocket *newSocket = new QTcpSocket();
    newSocket->bind(QHostAddress("0.0.0.0"), 0 , QAbstractSocket::ShareAddress);
    newSocket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);
    
    this->addPendingConnection(newSocket);

    emit internalNewConnection();
}
```

The communication is correct and communication with client is possible.

**[Second application]**

Try opening the socket using socket descriptor in the second application on the device:

```
bool TransmitterServer::initSocket(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
    m_tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket();
    m_tcpSocket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);

    if(m_tcpSocket->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState){
        qDebug() << "Socket connected";
        return true;
    }

    qDebug() << "Socket doesn't connected.";

    return false;
}
```

Try opening the socket using the address and port in the second application on the device:

```
bool TransmitterServer::initSocket(QString peerAddress, QString peerPort)
{
    m_tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket();

    if(m_tcpSocket->bind(QHostAddress(peerAddress), peerPort.toInt(), QAbstractSocket::ShareAddress)){
        qDebug() << "Socket binded";
        return true;
    }else{
        qDebug() << "Can't bind socket " << m_tcpSocket->error();
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Is it possible to achieve it on the server-side?**

Comment: See e.g. [File Descriptor Transfer over Unix Domain Sockets](https://copyconstruct.medium.com/file-descriptor-transfer-over-unix-domain-sockets-dcbbf5b3b6ec)

Comment: Or create socket in one process, then *fork* new processes which will "share" the descriptor.

Comment: With the above mentioned, *sharing* is really not a good idea, as you can't really control which process will get the connections on passive sockets, or receive data for connected sockets. Instead think about it as *ownership*: While it's possible to transfer ownership of a descriptor between processes, in reality only one single process (thread really) at a time have ownership of the descriptor.

Comment: Ok, fine, it's Linux theory, but why sharing socket doesn't work based on Qt and QTcpSocket?